# Implement reset password link for certain time or for one time use only in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, I am working on a project and want that their password should be destroyed after certain time.

**Here is my reset password code**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST.get('email')
        domain_name=get_current_site(request).domain
        token=str(random.random()).split('.')[1]
        link=f'http://{domain_name}/resetpassword/{token}'
        if not Registered_user.objects.filter(email=user_email).first():
            messages.error(request, "No user found with this email")
            return redirect('/confirmemail/')
        data = Registered_user.objects.get(email=user_email)
        data.token = token
        data.save()
        subject = 'Reset password'
        email_template = get_template('admin/email.html').render({'link': link})
        from_email = 'service@example.co'
        message = EmailMessage(subject, email_template, from_email, [user_email])
        message.content_subtype='html'
        message.send()
        messages.success(request, f'Shared reset password link at {user_email}')           
return render(request,'admin/forgotpassword.html',{'title':title})
```

Thanks for your help

requirement

**Need this reset link should be valid for one time use or for certain hours**

Comment: you can introduce an expiration timestamp to the token and check it when the link is accessed.